# I exceeded the default Undo limit, then went to Edit>Preferences and changed the limit. But I still can't use Ctrl+Z again. Help?

Tags: sculpting, sculpt-mode

[image: My project, mask on]

So, I wanted to create a body of hair for my character without having to do the usual process of adding another Ico Sphere (I'm trying to treat this sculpture as a traditional clay sculpture). I figured I should just use a mask to fill in the hairline. It wasn't a great plan, as I had to repeatedly Remesh the project. So, I tried to Ctrl+Z it all, and when I exceeded the Undo limit, I went to File>Revert to last save. The image I've attached is the Revert version, still not back to the original bald :') I belatedly increased the Undo limit and tried to CTRL+Z again, but it still wouldn't undo anymore. Did I doom myself by reverting? I don't know how to get rid of this. Is there a way to access all of my saves, rather than just my last session or most recent save?
Thanks for you time and consideration!
Edit- I'm told there is no way to fix this. Thanks for your guys' comments, I just wanted to know if I should fix this issue manually (which would take me a while) or if there was some other way. I've started doing the former!

Comment: Imagine this - you're walking, and every step you put down a rock. Each rock will stay there until you take 30 steps beyond it, at which point someone else will pick it up (Imagining a 30 step undo limit). Until you have taken 30 steps past any given rock, you can still go back and look at it, but after 30 steps, it's been picked up and is gone forever. Now, say, during your journey, you tell the person that's picking up the rocks to wait 60 steps instead - you can only still go back and examine the last 30 of the rocks at this point because the (second) set of 30 has already been picked up.

Comment: Imagine you're in the middle of a chess game and you've told your friend to only remember the last 5 moves you made. Then, suddenly, you turn to your friend and say, "Hey, buddy, can you remember the last 10 moves instead?" Your friend agrees, and you're thrilled and ask him "What were the last 10 moves I made?". He looks at you confused :D

Comment: Thanks for your guys' comments, I just wanted to know if I should fix this issue manually (which would take me a while) or if there was some other way. I've started doing the former!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The undo limit on Blender controls how many actions the software will store before deleting the oldest actions to make room for the newest, so increasing the undo limit retroactively unfortunately will not bring back older actions that have already been cleared from memory.